# Trimble GeoXH, XM, XT - Data logging without Terrasync or GPSCorrect?

Tags: gps, rinex, data-capture, trimble

Is it possible to capture data for post processing on a Trimble GeoXH, XT, or XM without using Terrasync or GPScorrect? Specifically I would like to create a RINEX file. A Trimble 4000 series receiver can log data internally, that can then be exported to a PC and converted into a RINEX file. Is this possible to do with a stock Geo XT, XH, XM?

Answer (score 2):

We (embarrassingly) purchased at GeoXT without software and were put in a position to *attempt* to obtain GPS data and post-process it. In my research I stumbled on this http://gpspp.sakura.ne.jp/rtklib/rtklib.htm and believe it may be a good lead - our office has not had much flexibility to look into the potential.

"*RTKLIB is an open source program package for standard and precise positioning with GNSS. RTKLIB consists of a portable program library and several application programs (APs) utilizing the library.*"

Comment: the quality of post processing with RTKLIB is it similar to post processing using trimble software ?

Answer (score 1):

**Ozi Explorer**

http://www.oziexplorer.com/ (should) read/convert Receiver Independent Exchange Format (RINEX)

Comment: I was hoping to capture the Trimble binary format carrier phase data. I don't think OziExplorer does anything other than NEMA. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told by a previous Pro XH owner that, when loaded on a Pocket PC with Windows Mobile 6, SpectraPrecision FAST Survey 3.1.12 works wonderfully with the old Trimble TerraSync based products.

I'm waiting for my retro Pocket PC to test.

Also, ArcPad and some others mobile softwares apps are compatible with the Trimble Standard Interface Protocol (TSIP). That protocol was developed on 1999... so, IN THEORY, any Trimble product with serial port communications from the 2000's onward SHOULD be compatible.