# Is it possible to postprocess Trimble .ssf files without Trimble Pathfinder Office?

Tags: trimble, ssf

Is it possible to postprocess Trimble .ssf files without Trimble Pathfinder Office (differential correction - our  sporadic use does not defend realtime correction subscription) ?
We only need the correction utility but the pathfinder package contains a lot more and is too expensive just for this.
I have not yet found open source software which supports ssf.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I haven't found an Open Source solution.

However, there is a Trimble extension in ArcMap called GPS Analyst that will post-process `.ssf` files. They have also released a new version for ArcGIS 10.1 called [Trimble Positions](http://www.trimble.com/mappingGIS/trimblepositions.aspx?dtID=key_benefits&) desktop addin that is the current ESRI solution.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer but [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10375/trimble-geoxh-xm-xt-data-logging-without-terrasync-or-gpscorrect) may give you some useful material.

RTKLIB is the reference open source post-processing solution, but it doesn't seem to support .ssf (yet?).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the SSF to RINEX utility included in the GPS Pathfinder Office (viewer mode requires no license).  Then use RTKLIB to post-process the data.  There might be issues with the RINEX file, though, see [SSF to RINEX problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223705/ssf-to-rinex-problem)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so any sofware available to apply differential correction to ssf file. only Pathfinder office can do this. If I can help you you can contact me to solve your problem.