# SSF to RINEX problem

Tags: pathfinder, rinex, post-processing, ssf

I used Pathfinder office 4.2 to export GeoXH data into RINEX format. It works right when I have only 1 point feature, however when I have multiple point features I get only 1 point feature in the resulting RINEX file.

I checked the RINEX file manually and it does only have 1 MARKER NAME and 1 MARKER NUMBER hence it only displays one of the features... 
I also checked the points in the software and found that all the points seem to be named "point_generic" (even though they have different attributes). 
Is there a way to change those names, or another way to export SSF to RINEX with multiple point features?

Answer (score 3):

Trimble Pathfinder exports RINEX in a way that supports using the RINEX files as base files, and base files are captured at a fixed location.

The easiest practical way to do what you want is to capture a separate SSF file over each feature, then export the separate SSF files to RINEX.  Alternatively you can split up a big multi-feature SSF file into separate files SSF for each feature using SSF Record Editor, but it is hard to describe what to retain and what to delete.  Reply if you are interested and I will try to describe the splitting process.

Remember that RINEX files saved from SSF are single frequency (L1 only) - this is a limitation of the RINEX export.